# How to treat blisters on burnt skin after initial period?

Tags: dermatology, burns, second-degree-burn

In google, there are plenty of articles about what to do (i.e. First Aid) when you get skin-burn (doing this or that...etc..). However, I was unable to find any solid article that refer to treating of blisters that form on burnt skin (after initial hour or two), and are there during next days and we may observe different scenarios ( after blister is filled with liquid):

A) About blisters - should we try to keep them untouched (thus, not it is necessary the liquid stayed there and not removed).

B) Even if the blister is popped accidentally, what to do (i.e. let it resurge itself ? or what. )

C) Accidental removal of the whole protective blister skin, while it is in the middle of healing (thus,  exposing the inner layer to the infection ). Is the inner layer considered still as "vulnerable" for infection, and should we treat same, as if we had treated the open wound (like as if skin was removed from the 1st minute of the accident)?

So, what are the correct guidelines/approaches for each case (A,B,C). Also, in case of child, who can't retain "loose bandages" even for 10 mins.

Comment: Instructions on treating blisters are all over the web. One random example that answers all your questions is here: https://www.webmd.com/first-aid/blisters-treatment. Since your searches had to have found some of these articles, I suspect we have an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) here. Which of your questions aren't answered by the WebMD article?

Comment: @CareyGregory thanks, i have been searching with "how to treat skin burn blisters" and google didnt lead me to those pages. Thank you! if you convert that to answer, I will select & upvote.

Comment: Btw, that article doesnt answer to `C)` from my question.

Comment: C is answered by "2. For a blister that has popped."

Comment: @CareyGregory ah, i missed one point. it mentions "gauze". as my specific case referred to child (under 1 yr, who can't retain "loose bondages" even for 10 minute, and neither our doctor advised to use "patch"-tapes, I was in uncertainty. However, as that article mentions gauze, I will use that instead of "loose bondage" which is meaningless for child).